# Linq search string word separate string

Tags: linq, search

I got a list of string. I want to do a search inside and return a new list. The search value is a string (sentence). Each word are split by a space.

So, I look at a way to search each string containing each word of the sentence.

sample :

```
list = {"abcdef", "abc", "ab", "cd ab"}

search "ab" => return list with "abcdef", "abc", "ab", "cd ab"
search "abc" => return list with "abcdef", "abc"
search "ab cd" => return list with "abcdef","cd ab"
```

its simple but I don't know how to do it with Linq in a single command. Something like

```
if l.contains(list)
```

where contains check every element of the list.

That may be simple, I just ask how. Or maybe a link to another post that I have not seen.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky one is your last case of "ab cd".

```
var list = new List<string> {"abcdef", "abc", "ab", "cd ab"};
var result = list.Where (w => "ab cd".Split().All (s => w.Contains(s)));
```

[Click here to see the proof that it catches all cases you've outlined.](http://ideone.com/3xjdx)

Comment: seems good, working. not tested full proof but look like that. Tank you

Answer (score 1):

```
if (list.Any(w => w.Contains(something))
```